# Using html5sql to create a sqlite database and retrieve records

Tags: sqlite

Based on this question [HTML5SQL retrieve records from web databases using SELECT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171168/html5sql-retrieve-records-from-web-databases-using-select-statements), i used the code from "http://html5sql.com" site to create and retrieve records from the database in my Android mobile Phone. In fact i used this method "$.get('demo-statements.sql',function(sql)" to create the database where in the "demo-statements.sql" file was the sql code to create the tables and insert the records in the database. The problem is when i use Greek characters in my phone i see rhombus with a questionmark inside the rhombus instead of the Greek characters.
Any idea why is that?
Thanks for help

Well i cleaned up the chrome's database and i noticed that the same problem came up when i run it on Chrome. When i use programmers tools and i click on Resources tab to see the database, the tables and the records i see the same characters. So when i console.log the HTML which creates the page i see also the strange characters...
Before use the "$.get('demo-statements.sql',function(sql)" method and wrote the sql code directly in Dreamweaver the characters where OK!

Comment: Something is screwing up character encoding. Try it on desktop as well (might be a bug in the mobile browser) and try adding debug statements that will dump the codepoints stored and loaded. Than if you don't notice the problem, post the results here and quote all the relevant code in the question (link to full source is fine, but the key parts must be quoted directly).

Comment: Also first of all, try just trivial function that will take the input and echo it back. Might be simply problem that you are trying to display the characters in a font that does not support Greek characters or similar problem completely unrelated to html5sql.

Comment: Well using notepad i saved the file 'demo-statements.sql' with UTF-8 codification and everything worked OK.
Thanks for help!